# UIImageView pixel-perfect `touches began` for non-transparent parts of UIImage

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, touchesbegan, user-interaction

developing iphone app, I have used a UIImageview and i have set an image of irregular shape

```
// uiimageview type shutter
shutter = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,32.5)];

//setting image on shutter
UIImage* shutterimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trayshutter.png"];
[shutter setImage:shutterimg];
// User interaction
shutter.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
```

and i get touches using touchesbegan

everything is fine, but issue is I also get events in all the rectangle  area occupied by the CGRectMake (i.e. 0,0,320,32.5) of imageview, whereas i require events only on the image (which is of shape of -----|||||-----).

How can i make sure that i get events only on the image and not on the rest of area covered by cgrectmake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  if ([touch view] == yourDesiredImage) {
    // Do something here
  }
}
```

EDIT: maybe you can try `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[tapGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(yourTouchMethod:)];
[tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[shutter addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
[tapGestureRecognizer release];
```

Comment: I have tried the same, also tried checking [touch view] with imageview object but issue remains the same.

Comment: actually i have made a class opencloseshutter which has this imageview and image , so i tried without checking and checking with imageview and image but no help..

Comment: I don't think this answers the question... the asker seemed to care about touches on the non-transparent parts of the image, whereas this just gets touches on the UIImageView CGRect as a whole.